# How to remain the color of the textbox even if you close the program.?

Tags: vb.net

What is the code for this problem?

Comment: Anything you do at runtime is lost when the application is closed, because it is stored in memory (the one used while the application is running). If you want something to remain across multiple executions you would have to store it in an external resource (e.g., a file or a database).

Comment: Or set it at design time.

Comment: @Mort Logically, but what you are doing at design time is precisely storing information in files (e.g., the executable). In any case, it seems implicit in the question that the OP wants to change the behaviour (= cannot be done at design time) and make such a change to remain.

Comment: It doesn't seem implicit at all. If you set the color at design time, it will "remain the color of the textbox even if you close the program". Unclear question. Unclear answer.

Comment: I voted to close your question as "unclear" because this is exactly what it is. We don't want to guess what you want to do. You need to tell your details to get an answer

Answer (score 1):

This is a very vague question, what sort of text box, a windows control, HTML or something else?

Assuming that you're using a windows form, then basically you want to save the color property to some kind of storage when the program closes, and use the same when it loads.

You can use the registry, an INI file or the applications app.config file to do this.

Comment: Why do you even bother to answer questions like this?

Answer (score 0):

I would use a setting. You can define a new setting with at type of System.Drawing.Color. On form load you can set the controls ForeColor (or BackColor) to the setting. On form unload you can save the properties current value. Here's a reference: https://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev11.query?appId=Dev11IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(ApplicationSettingsOverview);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.5)&rd=true